# Split a list with regex expression in python

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split a string using regex expression but I struggle to be efficient with it

My input is a string as a list with each line being an element of the list.

Some lines in the list are dates with always the same format which is `Weekday, Month Number, Year`. An example can be `Wednesday, March 16, 2022`or `Friday, April 8, 2022` and then the next elements in the list are text which has been typed this day, until the next date in the list.

I give you an example of what the list looks like :
`['Wednesday, March 16, 2022', 'bla-bla-bla', 'Hello World !', 'Friday, April 8, 2022', 'Can't wait for the weekend' ,'See you !']`

I'd like to have as output a list of list with each element of the list being a list of each string of the day, and the date being the first (or last) element of that list. At the moment, I tried to put the string in a big string and to use regex expressions to split the string ( I use this regex but I don't know if it is the right syntax `re.split(r'\s+ +\d\d,+ \d\d\d\d", big_string)`but I don't really believe in it because I think putting the split text into a list after will be very hard.

Does someone have any idea about how to do this ? I hope I was clear with my explanation.

Thanks everyone !

Comment: Do you want to say you have lists as text? Like `big_string = "['Wednesday, March 16, 2022', 'bla-bla-bla', 'Hello World !', 'Friday, April 8, 2022', 'Can't wait for the weekend' ,'See you !']"`? Then try `import ast` and then `print(ast.literal_eval(big_string))`

Comment: The original text has been splitted into a list as I show in my example yes.

Comment: What I tried was to get back to the original string which could look like ```'Wednesday, March 16, 2022\nbla-bla-bla\nHello World !\nFriday, April 8, 2022\nCan't wait for the weekend\nSee you !'``` but I don't believe a lot in this way of doing

Comment: Please post an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't know why my example is not a MCVE, but I can give you the expected output for this input. I'd like a list of list separated by dates so it would look like this : ```[['Wednesday, March 16, 2022','bla-bla-bla', 'Hello World !'],['Friday, April 8, 2022', 'Can't wait for the weekend' ,'See you !']]```Here there is two dates so a list of two list each with as a first element the date and then the strings which belong to this date. Is it clearer like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can start by parsing dates in your list with the dateutil module. After that, I recomend to create a dictionary with each day sentences in a list. Then you can parse that as you want and create other desired formats.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime as dt
# parser.parse('Wednesday, March 16, 2022') -> datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 0, 0)

# So looping over your list
# This will transform the date strings to python dates

new_list = []
for el in loopable_list:
    try:
        # Parse and transform into datetime string
        date_el = parser.parse(el)
        new_list.append(date_el)
    except:
        new_list.append(el)

# And now going foward to structure the problem
# I think its more appropriate to first create a dictionary 
# with each day being the index and a list with the remaing text
structured_data = {}
prev_el = 0
# Loops each element and check if its a date
for el in new_list:
    # If its a date, creates an element with empty list, 
    # and them appends the next elements to it
    if isinstance(el, dt)
        structured_data[stre(el)] = []
        prev_el = el
    else:
        sctructured_data[prev_el].append(el)
```

Comment: When I try to use your code, I get an error at the last loop : ```NameError: name 'isattr' is not defined```Do I need to import anything to have it defined ?  Also, with the first loop, I get a list of the same length but all element are parser, is that normal ? (I was expecting to only have the dates as parser objects but maybe I don't fully understand the code)

Comment: Okay, lets go in parts. Just fixed the error, suposed to be isinstance (that checks if the current element is a datetime object). And no, after the first loop, we get datetime objects and the remaing text that wasnt datetimes. To get the actual date string, you can str(datetime_object_you_want).

Comment: What we're doing in general is: Parse dates into std format and then create a dict with each element having a list of words.